# Using cross-validation to calculate feature importance "Some Questions"

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, cross-validation, feature-selection

I am currently working on a project. I already selected my features and want to check their importance. I have some questions if anyone can help me please.

1- Does it make sense if I use `RandomForestClassifier` with `cross-validation` to calculate the feature importance?

2- I tried it to calculate the feature Importance using the `cross_validate` function 
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html . The function provides the test_score and train_score results. The results I got with a `10 Fold cross-validation` were as follows:

**test_score** `[0.99950158, 0.9997231 , 0.9997231 , 0.99994462, 0.99977848, 0.99983386, 0.99977848, 0.9997231 , 0.99977847, 1.]`

**train_score** `[0.99998769, 0.99998154, 0.99997539, 0.99997539, 0.99998154,0.99997539, 0.99998154, 0.99997539, 0.99998154, 0.99997539]`,

Can anyone explain these results? And what does it indicate?

3- The `cross_validate` function has a parameter called `scoring`, which has different scoring values such as `accuracy`, `balanced_accuracy` and `f1`. What does the `scoring` parameter do? And what do these values mean? And how should I decide which one to choose? I already read the scikit-learn documentation but wasn't clear to me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question 1 is slightly out of scope here. For each run (fold) of cross-validation, you will get an array of importance for your features. Then how would you combine those into single importance per feature? There may be outputs which can show that a specific feature is important based on higher scores on different folds. But that may vary.

Now, `cross_validate` will return the default score of the estimator used inside it, unless the `scoring` param is set. So if you leave the `scoring`, it will use `RandomForestClassifier`'s `score()` method which returns accuracy.

(In scikit, all classifiers will return accuracy in `score()` and all regressors will return r-squared value)

So for your question 2: the returned scores are accuracies per cv fold.

If you do not want to use accuracy and want some other score, you may set the `scoring` param in`cross_validate`.